# Firebase catch not working on promise even tho not connected to internet

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know whether there's something I'm missing. I'm using firebase cloudstore as a backend to my app that I'm building with react-native / expo

If I use the get function on my collection and I'm not connected to the internet, the promise never seems to be resolved.

My code looks like

```
var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("user").doc(user.uid)
docRef.get()
.then(() => {
 //function in here
})
.catch(() => {
   alert('Please connect to the internet');
})
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this? or am I missing some fundamentals here?

Thanks

Comment: What is the console telling you? Specifically, the network tab.

Comment: Is your resolve call back working when connected?

Comment: Yes the callback is working as expected when connected. I can update my database no problem. In regards to the network tab. In order to try out what happens when I disconnect from the internet, I can't debug it, as it disconnects from the expo xde. I just find that that the app does nothing and the catch statement appears to be never invoked, as I receive no alert message

Comment: Okay it appears that the promise is being resolved. The time it takes to resolve is just taking a lot longer than I would expect. It's also varies regardless of the fact that I am still not connected to the internet.